# Unable to set up ADT for salesforce hybrid mobile app

Tags: android, eclipse, git, node.js, salesforce

I cloned SalesforceMobileSDK-Android repo from Git and built it using npm as suggested in the Git page. I created a sample app using forcedroid and imported the sample project into my bundled ADT. But I am not able to add Salesforce Mobile SDK as library into the project. Can anyone please suggest where am I going wrong here.[image]

Answer (score 4):

you should try this. first right click on your project in eclipse. go to properties , open java build path in left pane and in Order and Export tab check all checkbox. it it works then good. other wise you should check your manifest 
     is what version?

Comment: Hi as suggested i checked all checkboxes but in vain. Android manifest version is 1.0

Answer (score 3):

Exactly as @Kamal Kumar says :
you should try this. first right click on your project in eclipse. go to properties , open java build path in left pane and in Order and Export tab check all checkbox. it it works then good. other wise you should check your manifest is what version?

Answer (score 0):

Your app uses the SalesforceSDK as libery project so you need to import the SalesforceSDK project into eclipse as well. Have a look at this:

[Forcedroid Tutorial](http://www2.developerforce.com/de/mobile/getting-started/android#hybrid)